# Media="screen max-width  Подключить деррикторию

Tags: html, css

Так случилось, что достался кривой сайт на доработку, и сейчас через css нет физической возможности подключить стили для смартфонов. От старых веберов осталась отдельная дирректория с мобильной версией (http://www.site.ru/m/) Я хотел бы написать что бы при вхождении на сайт с мобилы подключалась отдельная дирректория, пишу `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen (max-width : 900px)" href="/m/index.php" />` но она не подключается - подскажите выход из ситуации

Comment: @нгш, так вам нужно стили подключить для мобильной версии или отправить пользователя на другую версию сайта?  
Если второе, то вам нужно определять с помощью PHP (или javascript), с чего зашли на сайт, и если с мобилки, то делать редирект на папку с мобильной версией сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/
выход из положения нашёл